# How to debug why my chatrooms are not appearing in React-Bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I really have tried every solution I can think of and the code seems to be fine. It is giving me no errors or signs of issues.

Objective - To display all the available chat rooms

Problem - Chat rooms are not appearing and in the source code the `<GroupList>` div is empty so no data is passing in..

Here's my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { ListGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';

function Sidebar() {
    const rooms = ["1st Room", "2nd Room"];
  return (
        <>
        <h2>Available Chat Rooms</h2>
        <ListGroup >
        {rooms.map((room, idx) => {
                <ListGroup.Item key={idx}>
                    {room}
                </ListGroup.Item>
            })}
            </ListGroup>
        </>
  );
}
export default Sidebar
```

```
const rooms = ["1st Room", "2nd Room"]; IS NOT PASSING INTO THE GROUP LIST.
```

I have also tried the following code aswell

```
import React from 'react';
import { ListGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';

function Sidebar() {
    const rooms = ["1st Room", "2nd Room"];
  return (
        <>
        <h2>Available Chat Rooms</h2>
        {rooms.map((room, idx) => {
                    <ListGroup key={idx}>
                <ListGroup.Item >
                    {room}
                </ListGroup.Item>
            </ListGroup>
            })}
        </>
  );
}
export default Sidebar
```

Both deliver no errors so I don't know where to start or what to be looking for. I have read the React-Bootstrap docs and to no avail.

Comment: Please give your post a meaningful title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use "{}" add a "return" inside of it. when you use "()" just put directly the element.

Example of using "()"

```
{rooms.map((item,idx)=> (
      <ListGroup.Item key={idx}>
        {item}
      </ListGroup.Item> 
) 
)};
```

Example of using "{}"

```
{rooms.map((item,idx)=> {
  return (
          <ListGroup.Item key={idx}>
            {item}
            </ListGroup.Item> 
  )
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Either:

```
{rooms.map((room, idx) => { // With curly braces, we have to return explicitly
               return ( 
                   <ListGroup.Item key={idx}>
                   {room}
                   </ListGroup.Item> 
               )
})}
```

Or:

```
{rooms.map((room, idx) => ( // implicit "return"
                   <ListGroup.Item key={idx}>
                   {room}
                   </ListGroup.Item> 
               )
)}
```

More info:
[Arrow functions, the basics](https://javascript.info/arrow-functions-basics)

Comment: Yep, happy coding!